# What customization is needed to change the term Superset in the URL

Tags: url, replace, customization, apache-superset

I need to change the term superset in the URL for Apache Superset hosted in my server. Tried to change the superset source code and couldn't achieve the result.

Eg : http://name.domain.com/superset/welcome has to be changed as http://name.domain.com/new-name/welcome

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using apache rewrite rules as below

1. Enable rewrite by executing command **sudo a2enmod rewrite**
2. Change the apache config file to add the following lines : 

   RewriteEngine on 

   RewriteRule "^/superset\/(.*)" "/new-name/$1" [R] 

   RewriteRule "^/new-name\/(.*)" "/superset/$1" [PT]
3. restart apache service